# How long did Killi's journey through "The City" took?

Tags: blame

From the first chapter until

> Killi restores the network interface gene

how long did it take? Years? Decades? Millenia?

Answer (score 3):

Reading Blame! you can see different scenes where Killy is injured. Sometimes before entering into sleep mode to recover and sometimes after recovering, you can see 'in first person' scenes where numbers depicting offline time are shown. I recall those counts being in hours and around tens of thousands to hundreds of thousands. So each time he is almost completely destroyed, several years pass by.

I'll update with page references and citations to everything I'm saying when I'm back home.

Anyway, that's subjective time from the Killy perspective:
He enters a dimensional rift when around the gravitational power generator, so he may have traveled far into the future or past after those chapters. It'd be hard to know, as his friends and enemies are all either dead or machines, and the megastructure has not many relatable temporal references.
Again, I'll check, but if I'm not mistaken, when moving within the megastructure with elevators some of them go at breathtaking speeds, approaching relativistic figures, and he spends several hundred hours in them.

TLDR: From the killy point of view, counting downtime, around millenia. From the world perspective: hard to know, but probably even more.

Disclaimer: I've only read and can only understand the english or the spanish translations. If anyone can read a japanese first edition, it may differ.